# SSH - How to include "-t command" in the ~/.ssh/config file

Tags: linux, ssh, root

I use [`~/.ssh/config`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config) file so that I can easily enter `ssh myserver` and it'll provide the correct username, port, hostname, identity file, etc.

However for many servers, the first thing I do is enter `su -` to log in as root. I can do this all in one command on the command line like so: `ssh myserver -t su -`. Is there something I can add to my `~/.ssh/config` file that'll do that for me? I want to be able to do `ssh myserver-root` and it'll do the same thing as `ssh myserver -t su -`?

I know about `PermitRootLogin`, that's off for this server, and I'm reluctant to turn that on. I'd much rather see if there's a way to do this using ssh on the client side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I'd approach this from the other direction - use 'command=' on the public key entry in your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the remote server, to run your "su -" command.

Then just use/reference the private key in your ~/.ssh/config file (IdentityFile option) for every host/alias ("myserver-root") you want to work this way.

The options available in authorized_keys(5) are documented in sshd(8).

Comment: Yes that does exactly what I want. :) I have full control over the ~/.ssh/authorized_key file on the server and have no problem with changing that.

Answer (score 10):

Use the force Luke!

use `RequestTTY force` in your `~/.ssh/config` for the desired host.

btw. this is also discussed here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27713/ssh-config-way-to-spectify-pseudo-tty-allocation-and-command-execution-like-sc/294468#294468

Comment: I believe this is the better answer to the original question

Answer (score 3):

Why not add a script to a dir in your path (or an alias for it) called rssh like:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $1 -t 'su -'
```

Then it is just:

```
rssh myServer
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any config option for pseudo-tty allocation in the OpenSSH source.

But I can give a tip regarding PermitRootLogin, Set it to:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

And allow only root logins with ssh-keys.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding something like this in ~/.bashrc on the server side?

```
if [ "$SSH_TTY" != "" ]; then su -; logout; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is probably a combination of [rkthkr](https://serverfault.com/questions/56086/ssh-how-to-include-t-command-in-the-ssh-config-file/56102#56102) and [jrg](https://serverfault.com/questions/56086/ssh-how-to-include-t-command-in-the-ssh-config-file/56181#56181). Use `PermitRootLogin` to require a key, then only put the key with the `command` keyword in root's authorized_keys file.